# Python Regular Expression with Greedy Groups

Tags: python, regex

This is the content of the input file.

```
 sb.txt
 JOHN:ENGINEER:35
```

These are the patterns that are used to evaluate the file.

```
finp = open(r'C:\Users\dhiwakarr\PycharmProjects\BasicConcepts\sb.txt','r')

for line in finp:
   biodata1 = re.search(r'([\w\W])+?:([\w\W])+?:([\w\W])+?',line)
   biodata2 = re.search(r'([\w\W]+?):([\w\W]+?):([\w\W]+?)',line)
   print('line is '+line)
   print('re.search(r([\w\W])+?:([\w\W])+?:([\w\W])+? '+biodata1.group(1)+' '+biodata1.group(2)+' '+biodata1.group(3))
   print('re.search(r([\w\W]+?):([\w\W]+?):([\w\W]+?) '+biodata2.group(1)+' '+biodata2.group(2)+' '+biodata2.group(3))
```

This is the output I got

```
line is JOHN:ENGINEER:35
re.search(r([\w\W])+?:([\w\W])+?:([\w\W])+? N R 3
re.search(r([\w\W]+?):([\w\W]+?):([\w\W]+?) JOHN ENGINEER 3
```

I have a couple of questions about the output it produces.

1. Why did the first search pattern match the last characters of JOHN, ENGINEER but matched the first character of 35  ? I was expecting the greedy character "?" to exit as soon as the first character of JOHN and ENGINEER were found.
2. Can someone help me understand how the placement of "+?" affect the output in
   either statement ?

Comment: What is the value each group should contain?

Comment: I'm not looking for any particular value in the groups. I'm just trying to understand why the last characters of JOHN, ENGINEER i.e 'N' and 'R' were matched respectively ? I was expecting greedy to quit matching as soon as the first characters were found in the first pattern biodata1. Also why did biodata2 match everything ?

Comment: So you were expecing to match the first character of each alphanumeric word?

Comment: Yes that what I was expecting but confused as to why the last characters are matched instead for group(1) & group(2) in biodata1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Difference between biodata1 and biodata2 is the place of the `parenthesis`

**biodata1 :**

```
([\w\W])+?:([\w\W])+?:([\w\W])+?
```

**Explanation:**

```
The parenthesis matches one rgument before : for group(1)
like wise for group(2)
But there is no ending criteria for group(3) so it matched the first letter 3 after :
```

**biodata2 :**

```
([\w\W]+?):([\w\W]+?):([\w\W]+?)
```

**Explanation:**

```
You are matching all the words and non-words before : whicj should atleast have 1 words for group(1)
like wise for group(2)
but for group(3) you are matching all the word and non-word after second:
```

**+?:**

```
This checks if there is at least one or more character matching the given regex if so match it
```

Comment: Thanks @Vignesh Kalai, but the wouldn't +? have quit as soon as 1 character "J" was found before : and then proceeded to next group ? in biodata1

Comment: No +? alctually mean it has to match atleast one character it can match more than one character

Comment: In biodata1 it can match only one character and you have given an end limit to that character that is : so it matches one character before `:`

Comment: How to modify this to match just one character at the beginning like "J" from "JOHN" and "E" from "ENGINEER" ?

Comment: @DhiwakarRavikumar I am not that pro-efficient in regex u may have to ask other person or post another question in regex tag  asking this question

Comment: Thanks I'll challenge myself to figure that out

Comment: @DhiwakarRavikumar all the best :)